# Active Directory LDAP Authentication using Spring Boot and Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to authenticate with organization ldap server. When I enter the credentials I'm facing this error. Can someone help?

[Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A7D, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839]; remaining name 'username=aestools,ou=people'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3MVy.png)

This is my configuration:

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("username={0},ou=people").contextSource()
        .url("ldap://ldap.example.com:389/dc=ms,ddc=ds,dc=example,dc=com").and().passwordCompare()
        .passwordAttribute("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to authenticate an account that can view the LDAP records or something, maybe this will work

```
  auth
    .ldapAuthentication()
    .userDnPatterns("username={0},ou=people")
    .contextSource()
    .managerDn("cn=admin,ou=people,dc=ms,dc=ds,dc=example,dc=com")
    .managerPassword("adminPassword123") 
    .url("ldap://ldap.example.com:389/dc=ms,dc=ds,dc=example,dc=com")
    .and()
    .passwordCompare()
    .passwordAttribute("password");
```

So basically you need to fill in `.managerDn()` and `.managerPassword()` with info of the account that has permission to view LDAP server's records. This Spring security LDAP is quite new to me, so sorry if my answer not work.